# CEM not Formatting with \\n or _Comma_

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have a Custom JavaScript button in SalesForce,the Line breaks inside the custom Email Message or CEM rather are not working are not working -- tried everything \n \n, \r, \r, 
 etc.. also neither is  *comma*.

I was wondering if there is a new process or how can I use line breaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a backend setting in DocuSign to enable `HTML input via API`. You need to contact your DocuSign Account Manager to enable that setting for your DS account. Once this setting is enabled then you can send HTML 
 type code in the email body of the envelope.

Comment: Hey thank you so much! I was going insane as to why nothing was....Silly me

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it resolves your qs